# GCC Static Link Error "undefined reference to `pthread_once'"

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I want to compile an C program but it gives me an weird error when I try to run it with "-static" arg.
I'm running these args `-static -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive -static-libgcc && strip linuxkurulum.sh.c`

The error:

```
linuxkurulum.sh.c: In function ‘main’:
linuxkurulum.sh.c:1163:16: warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format [-Wformat-contains-nul]
 1163 |        printf("\0");
      |                ^~
linuxkurulum.sh.c:1170:29: warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 255 bytes into a region of size 8 [-Wformat-overflow=]
 1170 |        sprintf(arg2,"source %s",pipename);
      |                             ^~  ~~~~~~~~
linuxkurulum.sh.c:1170:8: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 8 and 263 bytes into a destination of size 15
 1170 |        sprintf(arg2,"source %s",pipename);
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): in function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x17): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o): in function `BIO_lookup_ex':
(.text+0xd02): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o): in function `BIO_gethostbyname':
(.text+0x75): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2.o): in function `uw_init_context_1':
(.text+0x1f05): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_lock_new':
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_read_lock':
(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_write_lock':
(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_unlock':
(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_lock_free':
(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once':
(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_init_local':
(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_set_local':
(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_cleanup_local':
(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `openssl_init_fork_handlers':
(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_get_local':
(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried adding `-pthread` and `-lpthread` args but didn't worked. I also upgraded my Ubuntu VPS Server to 20.04LTS.

Comment: `.... && strip linuxkurulum.sh.c` ?? Please show exact code as being executed from the cmd line. Do you really have `&&` on your command line? Why is the code filename extension `.sh.c`? Numerous things to explain here. Please edit Q to include the minimal amount of `C` code that will cause this problem to appear. Readers will want to copy/paste into their environment to try and fix it. Good luck!

Comment: I'm vaguely remembering that the order of the `ld` arguments can cause problems like this. Try putting the lowest level (`-lpthread` , etc) first? Good luck.

Comment: AND so this works if you leave out `-static`?

Comment: @shellter Yes, If I leave `-static` it works. This is an shell script obfuscator. It takes the shell script, base64 encodes it, then AES-256 encodes it, then it turnes them to `c` program. By the way `-lpthread` didn't work out for me.

Comment: WIthout seeing how you have setup you `#include`s, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var and other items, readers can't even guess at what might be wrong. Again, the smallest amount of code (and the cmds that try to compile/build it) that illustrates the problem are required. Good luck.